# How to display database structure in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Is there any way to generate a report of my database structure using phpMyAdmin?  What I would like is a table format like the following, and an Entity Relationship table.

```
Table name: List
Description: Subscriber list information 

Field           Type        Null        Description
ListID          Int         N   
ListName        Varchar     N   
ListFromName    Varchar     N           Default person represent for the mail
ListReplyTo     Varchar     N           Default return address
ListSubject     Varchar     N           Default subject title of mail
ListRemindSub   Int         N           Whether notify when people subscribe
ListRemindUnSub Int         N           Whether notify when people unsubscribe
ListCreateDate  Date        N   


Table name: Campaign
Description: Mail campaign information

Field           Type        Null        Description
CampID          Int         N   
CampReplyTo     Varchar     N           Specific return mail
CampFromName    Varchar     N           The person represent for the mail
CampSubject     Varchar     N           Subject title of mail
CampFb          Int         N           Whether include Facebook reminder
CampGA          Int         N           Whether include Google Analytic
```

Comment: You can query the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` database.

Comment: A detail blog: http://goo.gl/0z3vFE

Answer (score 5):

select DB, go to export, select tables that you want the structure (top left),deselect "DATA"(middle-center) and select a name and you will be able to export only the structure.

[image]

or go to your "database" then "check all" (just below the tables) and change the option from "With Selected:" to "print view".  it will show the relations too, and it will looks like this:[image]

Answer (score 4):

DISCLAIMER : I do not use phpmyadmin

From the mysql client, you can run

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE List\G
SHOW CREATE TABLE Campaign\G
```

It will show the table structure and associated indexes

In phpmyadmin, there is a `Structures` Tab to view the Table Columns

To run the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` commands I mentioned above, try executing them in the SQL or Query Tab. If phpmyadmin does not like my command line versions of the `SHOW CREATE TABLE ... \G` commands, then run them in the SQL or Query Tab with semicolons:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE List;
SHOW CREATE TABLE Campaign;
```

Comment: You can also run this in phpmyadmin by first selecting the database, and then clicking the SQL tab. That's a bit easier than exporting the db while unselecting the data section

Answer (score 3):

1. You can get that information from PHPMyAdmin by clicking the "Data Dictionary" link at the bottom of the list of tables in the database.
2. I thought that PHPMyadmin would create an ERD or database documentation, but I cannot seem to find the link. However you can use MySQL workbench (http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)  to generate an ERD by connecting to your database or from an SQL file export

Comment: I never noticed the Data Dictionary link. It saved me a lot of time!

Answer (score 1):

The print view of phpmyadmin is pretty good. Go to the "structure" tab..

[image: the structure tab for a table in phpmyadmin]

Then go to bottom and find the "print" link... you will be rewarded with a lovely view like this:

[image]

this has most of what you want... Your report was very text oriented and you might be looking at more like an ascii-art type output, and so I am not sure if you want this level of pretty printing or not. But if you want something that just prints well-enough, and does not take time to get to, this works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

> What I would like is a table format like the following, and an Entity
> Relationship table.

You can generate a entity relationship diagram and table structures from an existing database and tables.

- From **phpMyAdmin** - Select the database from the left-side panel (see picture below).
- Then, on the top panel (or TAB), select the `More -> Designer.` This opens the Designer panel, generates and shows the diagram with the tables in the database and their relationships. Further, you can edit this diagram.

The following is the **Designer** panel (using phpMyAdmin 5.2.1 connecting to MySQL 8) with an example of orders and order_detail tables:

[image]

The **Designer** panel has an option, **Export Schema**. This generates a PDF document with the diagram and the table structures. The PDF report with table structures (the actual report had four pages - list of tables, each table with its structure and the diagram):

[image]

[image]